# $H_1(S^1)$ with Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology

could you help me on the following? I decompose $S^1$ as $X^+:=S^1\setminus \{-e_1\}$ and $X^-:=S^1\setminus \{e_1\}$. In order to calculate the first singular homology group of the 1-sphere I consider the following section of the MV-sequence:

$\to H_1(X^+)\oplus H_1(X^-)\to H_1(S^1)\to H_0(X^+\cap X^-)\to H_0(X^+)\oplus H_1(X^-)\to$

Now the $X^+,X^-$ are contractible and hence vanish in homology. $X^+\cap X^-$ is homotopic equivalent to $S^0$ and so their homology groups are isomorphic and finally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ as is $H_0(S^0)$. This yields:

$$0 \to H_1(S^1)\to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\to$$

Hence the connecting homomophism is injective and surjects on ist image that is equal to the kernel of the inclusion map in homology $H_0(i_1,i_2)$.

Now I am stuck in computing this. I read a lot about choosing base points in $X^+$, $X^-$. There are several questions I have regarding this, but it might be most helpful if someone could explain (please in detail) how one do proceed from here on in order to calculate the kernel as I am very confused by now.

Thank you very much for your kind help!

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee it might be considered rude to explicitly ask someone to answer a question, especially one that's not specialized.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Sorry - but I thought the website itself encourages this, with "Know someone who can answer this question? Share it ... etc. etc."

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee the share function links to various forms of social media. Active members of the site tend to keep an eye on relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visualize $X^+$ as the left side of the circle and $X^-$ as the right, then $X^+\cap X^-$ is the union of the top half and the bottom half of the circle. Each connected component contributes a generator to $H_0$, which can be identified with any point of that component, positively oriented. A finite collection of points $\sum a_i x_i$ with orientation, all in one connecte component $a_i\in \pm 1$, corresponds to the class $\sum a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, the summand in $H_0$ corresponding to that component. From this it's straightforward to check that the kernel of your map is $(a,-a)\cong \mathbb{Z}$: explicitly, the map is $(a,b)\mapsto (a+b,a+b)$. This gives the result.

Comment: If I take, say $P\in$ top half and $Q\in$ bottom half then $P+Q$ is an element in $H_0(X^+\cap X^-)$? If I Project this to $H_0(X^+)\oplus H_0(X^-)$ how can I see what the kernel of $H_0(i_1,i_2)$ is?

Comment: Yes, it's $(1,1)$, so it goes to $(1+1,1+1)$ under $(i_1,i_2)$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you derive that the map is $(a,b)\mapsto (a+b,a+b)$?

Comment: @Ratatouille It's just, $(a,b)$ means $a$ points in the top and $b$ in the bottom, which corresponds to $a+b$ points either on the right or on the left.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I got it!