# Quick question about Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm looking over some notes from a first class in algebraic topology and in computing the homology groups for $S^1$ we write the exact sequence:

$ 0 \rightarrow H_1(S^1) \rightarrow H_0(U\cap V) \overset{A}\rightarrow H_0(U) 
 \oplus H_0(V) \rightarrow H_0(S^1) \rightarrow 0 $

Where $A: \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a+b \\ -(a+b) \end{pmatrix}$

I should say that we chose U and V in the obvious way so that $S^1$ is just a union of the two, and the intersection is the disjoint union of two points.

In my notes I have written: $H_0(S^1) = \text{coker}(A) = (\mathbb{Z} \oplus\mathbb{Z})  / (\mathbb{Z}\oplus\{0\}) $

My questions are twofold:

1. Where does this $A$ come from?
2. Why exactly is $H_0(S^1)$ the cokernel of $A$? I thought the homology groups were : $H_n(S^1) = \dfrac{\ker(\partial_n)}{im(\partial_{n+1})}$ 
   , but this is a sequence of homology groups...

Answer (score 1):

Here, $A=(i_*,j_*)$ where $i_*, j_*$ are induced by the two inclusions, $i:U\cap V\hookrightarrow U$ and $j:U\cap V\hookrightarrow V$. That is $A(m)=\big(i_*(m),j_*(m)\big),\forall m\in H_0(U\cap V).$

Note that, the map $B:H_0(U) 
 \oplus H_0(V) \rightarrow H_0(S^1)$ as in below exact sequence, is surjective.

$$0 \rightarrow H_1(S^1) \rightarrow H_0(U\cap V) \overset{A}\rightarrow H_0(U) 
 \oplus H_0(V) \overset{B}\rightarrow H_0(S^1) \rightarrow 0.$$

So using **First Isomorphism Theorem of Modules** we have, $$H_0(S^1)\simeq\frac{H_0(U) 
 \oplus H_0(V)}{\text{ker}(B)}=\frac{H_0(U) 
 \oplus H_0(V)}{\text{im}(A)}=\frac{\text{co-domain of }A}{\text{im}(A)}=\text{ co-kernel of } A.$$

Comment: $B$ is surjective as the above exact sequence gives that, $\text{im}(B)=\text{ker}(0)=0$. Also from the above exact sequence we have, $\text{ker}(B)=\text{im}(A)$.

Comment: When you include why are the generators added exactly?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you say somtheing more?

Comment: I just mean that, we have two generators of $H_0(U \cap V)$  which are the a and b entries in that matrix, right?  then when they get included into $H_0(u) \oplus H_0(v)$ why are they being summed? What does the sum actually mean?

Comment: You can check this here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430192/h-1s1-with-mayer-vietoris-sequence?rq=1

Comment: Another thing is that, you may take, $A=(i_*,-j_*)$. Your note contains this assumption.

Comment: So for example if I was looking at the torus similarly divided into two components: A being the left half and B the right half, so $A \cap B$ is retractable onto $S^1$ disjoint union with $S^1$, would the map be exactly the same? Because if you have a generator in the union it will also be a generator of U or V